# Centering a form HTML/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do I centering this form? No matter what I've tried (changing around the div classes, the styles, etc. it still does not center).

I've tried looking at using flex box and other tools but regardless of what I do, if something gets centered, the input field stays to the far left.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row text-center">
  <form>
    <div class="fc">
      <div class="fg cg">
        <h3>
          Name
        </h3>
        <input class="fc"style="width: 35%" type="text"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="fa">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: note that `<input>` is an empty tag. Means it has no closing tag. As such `</input>` is invalid as it does not exist.

Comment: Replace text-left with text-center

Comment: @Grumpy when I do that, the input field still stays on the left of the page

Comment: add `margin: 0 auto;` to your form

Comment: I've tried that here: jsfiddle.net/TestFiddle1001/x8et6ydq/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make the form a column, then `.text-center` works:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row text-center">
  <form class="col-12">

    <h3>
      Name
    </h3>
    <input class="fc" style="width: 35%" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <form>
        <h3>
          Name
        </h3>
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't really work for me, it fails to center the input field

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` like @Sysix has said in the comments

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row text-center">
  <form style="margin: 0 auto">
      <div class="fg cg">
        <h3>
          Name
        </h3>
        <input class="fc"style="width: 35%" type="text"></input>
      <div class="fa">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways of centering. But since you are using Bootstrap I thought I'd try it using Bootstrap classes.

I use the grid system to build a row with one big column spanning the entire row. I wrap the form in a div with a utility class `d-flex` and modify it with `justify-content-center` to center it.

Inside the form I use the `form-row`. Then use `form-group` to indicate a column inside the `form-row`. To fix formatting I put `form-control` on the input.

And finally I put the button on a seperate `form-row`. This solves your problem with only bootstrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">

  <div class="col-12">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

      <form>
        <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text">
          
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

          <div>
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Submit</btn>
            </div>
            
          </div>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the style

```
margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
```

Will also center anything for future reference

Also someone has already asked this before here:
[Centering a form in bootstrap not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68028095/centering-a-form-in-bootstrap-not-working/68028735#68028735)